# saving a file when server is terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm try to save a content to a file when my node js (express) server is terminated, somehow the file is empty.

```
    function exitHandler() {

        //.......

        fs.writeFile('graph.txt', Graph, 'utf8', (err) => {
            if (err != null) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });
    }


    // Bring in our dependencies
    const express = require('express');

    global.fs = require('fs');

    //  Connect all our routes to our application.
    app = express();

    // Turn on the server!
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('App listening on port 3000');.
    });

    // Catches exit event
    process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null));

    // Catches ctrl+c event
    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
        exitHandler();
        process.exit(-1);
    });

    // Catches "kill pid" (for example: nodemon restart)
    process.on('SIGUSR1', exitHandler.bind(null));
    process.on('SIGUSR2', exitHandler.bind(null));

    // Catches uncaught exceptions
    process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null)

);
```

If I delete the `process.exit(-1)` it save content to the file, but never exit the program, and call the event of `'exit'`.

thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but since `fs.writeFile` is asynchronous the application might exit before the underlying I/O is actually executed. Can you try [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options), instead?

Answer (score 2):

The `exitHandler` function is asynchronous. You're calling `process.exit` before the file gets saved. You should use a callback function:

```
function exitHandler(callback) {

    //.......

    fs.writeFile('graph.txt', Graph, 'utf8', (err) => {
        if (err != null) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
          callback();
        }
    });
}

// ...

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    exitHandler(() => process.exit(-1));
});
```

Or, as schroffl suggested in comments, you can use `fs.writeFileSync` instead of `fs.writeFile`:

```
function exitHandler() {

    //.......

    fs.writeFileSync('graph.txt', Graph, 'utf8');
}
```